# Why is my program outputting the wrong number of days?

Tags: python

So I am writing a program to work out  the number of days you have been alive after imputting your birthday. There is a problem as i am getting the wrong number of days but can figure out why. i inputted my birthday as 04/04/19 and i got 730625 days which is clearly wrong.

```
import datetime #imports module

year = int(input("What year were you born in"))

month = int(input("What month where you born in (number)"))

date = int(input("What date is your birthday? "))

birthdate = datetime.date(date, month, year) #converts to dd/mm/yy

today = datetime.date.today() #todays date

daysAlive = (today - birthdate).days #calculates how many days since birth

print("You have been alive for {} days.".format(daysAlive)) #outputs result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially got the same error as you but then I checked my code and managed to fix my mistake.

So your DOB is `04/04/19`, when you input that into `datetime.date()` and it looks at the value for `year` which is `19`, it will treat that as `0019`. As in 19 AD, not `2019`. You should make sure that you input the full year.

Also like [SimonN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11432434/simonn) said, the parameters for `datetime.date()` are `year, month, day`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

You have the parameters the wrong way round in `datetime.date` they should be `(year,month,day)`

Answer (score 1):

datetime takes arguments as `(year, month, date)`. Note that you cannot enter year like `09` for `2009`. Datetime will count it as `0009-MM-DD`. You have to enter complete year in the input as `2009`

```
...
birthdate = datetime.date(year, month, date)
...
```

So, with your input, the output for me is (It may differ with your timezone):

> ```
> You have been alive for 170 days.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

[`class datetime.date(year, month, day)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date)
should be in the format `yy/mm/dd`.

Try this code for Python **3.6** or higher,
because of [f-stings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings):

```
import datetime

year = int(input("What year were you born in: "))
month = int(input("What month were you born in (number): "))
day = int(input("What day were you born in: "))

birth_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)  # converts to yy/mm/dd
today = datetime.date.today()  # todays date

days_alive = (today - birth_date).days  # calculates how many days since birth
print(f"You are {days_alive} days old.")  # outputs result
```

Check the answer using [other sources](http://jalu.ch/coding/days/en).